# Need Convert Binary file to Txt file

Tags: c++

I have a dat(binary) file but i wish to convert this file into Ascii (txt) file using c++ but i am very new in c++ programming.so I juct opend my 2 files:myBinaryfile and myTxtFile but I don't know how to read data from that dat file and then how to write those data into new txt file.so i want to write a c+ codes that takes in an input containing binary dat file, and converts it to Ascii txt in an output file. if this possible please help to write this codes. thanks

Sorry for asking same question again but still I didn’t solve my problem, I will explain it more clearly as follows: I have a txt file called “A.txt”, so I want to convert this into binary file (B.dat) and vice verse process. Two questions:
1.  how to convert “A.txt” into “B.dat” in c++
2.  how to convert “B.dat” into “C.txt” in c++ (need convert result of the 1st output again into new ascii file)

my text file is like (no header):

1st line: 1234.123 543.213 67543.210 1234.67 12.000
2nd line: 4234.423 843.200 60543.232 5634.60 72.012

it have more than 1000 lines in similar style (5 columns per one line).

Since I don’t have experiences in c++, I am struggle here, so need your helps. Many Thanks

Comment: What do you mean converting binary files to text files? Do you want to just create a [hex dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) of the binary? Does this binary file have a specific file format structure? Does this binary file carry useful data that you would like to convert to a human-usable form? For example, the binary of a `*.doc` file is incomprehensible to humans, but when opened in Microsoft Word you can obtain the underlying text, formatting and all, in a way humans can easily understand. You need to be  a lot more specific than "I want to convert a binary file to a text file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy:

1. Create target or destination file
   (a.k.a. open).
2. Open source file in `binary` mode,
   which prevents OS from translating
   the content.
3. Read an octet (byte) from source
   file; `unsigned char` is a good
   variable type for this.
4. Write the octet to the destination
   using your favorite conversion, hex,
   decimal, etc.
5. Repeat at 3 until the read fails.
6. Close all files.

Research these keywords:  `ifstream, ofstream, hex modifier, dec modifier, istream::read, ostream::write`.

There are utilities and applications that already perform this operation.  On the *nix and Cygwin side try `od`, *octal dump` and pipe the contents to a file.

There is the `debug` utility on MS-DOS system.

A popular format is:

```
AAAAAA    bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb   bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb   cccccccccccccccc  
where:  
  AAAAAA -- Offset from beginning of file in hexadecimal or decimal.
  bb     -- Hex value of byte using ASCII text.
  c      -- Character representation of byte, '.' if the value is not printable.
```

Please edit your post to provide more details, including an example layout for the target file.

### Edit:

A complex example (not tested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const unsigned int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
const unsigned int WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * READ_BUFFER_SIZE;

unsigned char read_buffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
unsigned char write_buffer[WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    int program_status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    static const char hex_chars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    do
    {
        ifstream srce_file("binary.dat", ios::binary);
        if (!srce_file)
        {
            cerr << "Error opening input file." << endl;
            break;
        }
        ofstream dest_file("binary.txt");
        if (!dest_file)
        {
            cerr << "Error creating output file." << endl;
        }

        // While no read errors from reading a block of source data:
        while (srce_file.read(&read_buffer[0], READ_BUFFER_SIZE))
        {
            // Get the number of bytes actually read.
            const unsigned int bytes_read = srce_file.gcount();

            // Define the index and byte variables outside
            //   of the loop to maybe save some execution time.
            unsigned int i = 0;
            unsigned char byte = 0;

            // For each byte that was read:
            for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i)
            {
                // Get source, binary value.
                byte = read_buffer[i];

                // Convert the Most Significant nibble to an
                //   ASCII character using a lookup table.
                // Write the character into the output buffer.
                write_buffer[i * 2 + 0] = hex_chars[(byte >> 8)];

                // Convert the Least Significant nibble to an
                //   ASCII character and put into output buffer.  
                write_buffer[i * 2 + 1] = hex_chars[byte & 0x0f];
            }

            // Write the output buffer to the output, text, file.
            dest_file.write(&write_buffer[0], 2 * bytes_read);

            // Flush the contents of the stream buffer as a precaution.
            dest_file.flush();
        }
        dest_file.flush();
        dest_file.close();
        srce_file.close();
        program_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } while (false);
    return program_status;
}
```

The above program reads 1MB chunks from the binary file, converts to ASCII hex into an output buffer, then writes the chunk to the text file.

Comment: sorry help me to correct "while (srce_file.read(&read_buffer[0], READ_BUFFER_SIZE))","dest_file.write(&write_buffer[0], 2 * bytes_read);"lines thanks

Comment: i got errors in line 33 invalid conversion from `unsigned char*' to `char*'
33   initializing argument 1 of `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'

Comment: also, dest_file.write(&write_buffer[0], 2 * bytes_read);
60 invalid conversion from `unsigned char*' to `const char*'
what is the mean that invalid convertion from unsigned char to char or const char? If you can, help me to correct these 2 lines. Thank you

Comment: @aki: Use a *cast*:  `srce_file.read((char*)(&read_buffer[0]));`.  Similarly with the `write`.

Comment: Thanks Thomos for helps, yes now it's complied but I can not see anythings in my output binary.txt file, it is a zero file.

Comment: @aki:  Use a *debugger* and find out if the data is converted correctly into the `write_buffer`.  Worst case, you can print out the 2 values after they are written into the buffer.

Comment: @aki:  The `read` method may set the *failbit* and the *eofbit* when it reads less than `READ_BUFFER_SIZE`.  Change the program to accommodate for these statuses.

Comment: actually i didn't get your comments since i am poor in c++, but my while loop is not working properly i guess because: after this line <codes>while (srce_file.read((char*)&read_buffer[0], READ_BUFFER_SIZE))while (!srce_file.eof())<codes> i put cout<< " i am inside"; it cann't see in output. I change while(!srce_file.eof()) insted of your codes, then it's going to the loop but no stop.

Answer (score 2):

All files are just a stream of bytes. You can open files in binary mode, or text mode.  The later simply means that it may have extra newline handling.

If you want your text file to contain only safe human readable characters you could do something like [base64 encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) your binary data before saving it in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding that the difference between a binary file and a test file is in the interpretation of the contents.

Comment: of course, i don't know diffrence between this 2 files exacltly. when write a binary file, is it possible to write it line by line like in ascii file?